# How do you call a X Y bundle pack?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if you need to put a dash (-) or a slash (/) or something else, because both of them looks odd to me.

This particular sentence illustrates why I think it looks odd:

> This is a Nintendo Labo-LEGO bundle pack that will allow your children
>   to express their creativity at a fraction of the cost if you would
>   have bought them separately.

The dash looks a bit weird here if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is probably best with hyphen, as it is a joining of the Nintendo and the LEGO:

- **Nintendo Labo-LEGO bundle pack**

The slash `/` generally has a meaning implying alternatives, the hyphen `-` shows a joining of various kinds.

In many cases you can use either.

- The **Jekyll/Hyde** character represents a kind of duality ... [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Case_of_Dr_Jekyll_and_Mr_Hyde)
- The **yellow-blue** colour combination is one of his favourites

In shades of meaning slash is saying "you can call it either", the hyphen is saying "it is both".

**Specialist notes for printing** Stylebooks for printed works often suggest a preference for the hyphen, and in printed works there is a distinction between hyphen (short line for joining compound words `-`), and the dash (longer line for ranges of numbers, in manuscripts often written `--`, and even longer dashes "three-em dash" `---` for specialist purposes such as bibliographies.)  "A blue-green room" means a colour halfway between blue and green; "a blue--green room" would be a mixture of blue and green.  The exact usage depends on the particular house style.  For your example, *Hart's Rules* (Oxford University Press style guide) would give an en-dash.

Answer (score 1):

The forward slash is a common way to indicate a combination (or in context a pair of alternatives).

> The HP Black/Tri-color pack has two ink cartridges, and is cheaper than buying black and color cartridges separately.
>
> Pies for sale!  Chicken/steak/beef-and-onion:  £2.95
>
> Would you like to read my Kirk/Spock short story?